# ViewController switching animation like in the Path.app

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, path

Is there any open source codes achieve the viewController switching animation as appears in Path.app? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a bunch of different ones for you to check out - http://bitly.com/bundles/o_27ukkruo5l/1

I've used JASidePanel recently and it worked well.  Hope that helps.